# How to pass options value from each table row?

Tags: php, html-select

I am creating a table with rows which has options in each cells. The options are received from database table. Since each row has a options cell, I have to receive the value from each row. In select tag, the 'name' is incremented with the rows. But I am only getting the value of the last row.

Attaching the code section here.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $_GET['pno']; $i++) {
                echo'<tr>';
                echo "<td>$i</td>";
                echo '<td><select name="prod_$i">'; echo "prod_$i";
                //Query for production table gets processed.
                $qry_pr="SELECT * FROM production";
                $result_pr=mysql_query($qry_pr);
                $rows_pr=mysql_affected_rows($con);
                //Production options get filled from the table data.
                for($j=0;$j<=$rows_pr;$j++)
                {
                    $res_arr_pr=mysql_fetch_array($result_pr);
                    echo "<option value=$res_arr_pr[0]>$res_arr_pr[1]</option>";
                    //$res++;
                }
                //mysql_close($con);
                echo '</select></td>';
                echo '<td><select name="prod_mu_$i">';
                //Query for measurement_unit table gets processed.
                $qry_mu="SELECT * FROM measurement_unit";
                $result_mu=mysql_query($qry_mu);
                $rows_mu=mysql_affected_rows($con);
                //Unit options get filled from the table data
                for($k=0;$k<=$rows_mu;$k++)
                {
                    $res_arr_mu=mysql_fetch_array($result_mu);
                    echo "<option value=$res_arr_mu[0]>$res_arr_mu[1]</option>";
                }
                echo '</td>';
                echo '</tr>'; echo "prod_$i";
            }
            echo'</table><br>';
```

Hope I am clear with the query.
Thank you.

Comment: This problem is solved. Thanks to all the 3 people who helped.

Answer (score 2):

You have placed the SQL Query inside the for loop making it heavy. Because it will perform the same query over and over again. If you tweak the code a little you can use perform a single query and use that for all loop iterations.

```
<?php
//initialize blank 
$productions = $measurements = '';

// create the production select box
$qry_pr="SELECT * FROM production";
$result_pr=mysql_query($qry_pr);
if( mysql_num_rows($result_pr) )
{
    $productions .= "<select name='prod_%index%'>";
    while( $rec_pr = mysql_fetch_row($result_pr) )
    {
        $productions .= "<option value='{$rec_pr[0]}'>{$rec_pr[1]}</option>";
    }
    $productions .= "</select>";
}

// create the measurement select box
$qry_mu="SELECT * FROM measurement_unit";
$result_mu=mysql_query($qry_mu);
if( mysql_num_rows($result_mu) )
{
    $measurements .= "<select name='prod_mu_%index%'>";
    while( $rec_mu = mysql_fetch_array($result_mu) )
    {
        $measurements .= "<option value='{$rec_mu[0]}'>{$rec_mu[1]}</option>";
    }
    $measurements .= "</select>";
}
?>


<table>
<?php for($i=1;$i<=$_GET['pno'];$i++): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo str_replace('%index%',$i,$productions); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo str_replace('%index%',$i,$measurements); ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endfor; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

mysql_affected_rows will only give you the number of affected rows by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query. Your performing a SELECT, so the `$rows_mu` value will be wrong.

Instead of:

```
$rows_mu=mysql_affected_rows($con);
//Unit options get filled from the table data
for($k=0;$k<=$rows_mu;$k++)
{
    $res_arr_mu=mysql_fetch_array($result_mu);
    echo "<option value=$res_arr_mu[0]>$res_arr_mu[1]</option>";
}
```

try this:

```
//Unit options get filled from the table data
while ($res_arr_mu = mysql_fetch_array($result_mu)) 
{
   echo "<option value=$res_arr_mu[0]>$res_arr_mu[1]</option>";
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i will try this after the original problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
echo '<td><select name="prod_$i">'; echo "prod_$i";
```

to:

```
echo '<td><select name="prod_' . $i . '[]">'; echo "prod_$i";
```

Comment: But I still cant capture the option selected by the user in this way from each rows. How should I receive the variable in the 'action' page?

Comment: in the action page you can `print_r($_POST);` or `print_r($_GET);` depending on your form method, this will show you a list of all variables passed

Comment: Yes with print_r I came to know that the array is passed. Now how do I extract the individual key- value from the passed array?

Comment: you can use `$_POST["prod_" . $i]` which would return an array, obviously this must be done in a loop with `$i` as the variable.